# Dividing a string into two parts and selecting into two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have a string with a special character `:` like:

```
XYZ:xyz@mail.com
```

I want to divide this string into two sub-strings and select into variables. The special character `:` is just a separator.

```
@variable1=XYZ
@variable2=xyz@mail.com
```

Please guide me on how it is possible.

Comment: will there always be a colon in the string ? How should it be handled if there isn't one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String Dividing Guide:

1. Use [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the position of `:`.
2. Use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to grab all the characters before the position of `:`, and put them into `@variable1`.
3. Use `SUBSTRING` to grab all the characters after the position of `:`, and store them into `@variable2`.

A possible implementation:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max), @variable1 varchar(max), @variable2 varchar(max);
SET @string = 'XYZ:xyz@mail.com';

SELECT
  @variable1 = SUBSTRING(S, 1, P - 1),
  @variable2 = SUBSTRING(S, P + 1, L - P)
FROM (
  SELECT
    S = @string,
    P = CHARINDEX(':', @string),
    L = LEN(@string)
) s;

SELECT @variable1, @variable2;
```

Output:

```
-------------------- --------------------
XYZ                  xyz@mail.com
```

Comment: I know how you love details, try to move the colon in the string.

Comment: Not sure I understand your meaning. If you meant changing the colon's position, well, I have just tried it, nothing peculiar happened. Did you by chance mean 'remove'? (I own that my solution is not designed to treat the absence of the colon, but that wasn't asked for.)

Answer (score 2):

If ':' is missing, @v1 will be null

```
DECLARE @v1 varchar(20) 
DECLARE @v2 varchar(20)

DECLARE @s varchar(20)
SET @s = 'XYZ:xyz@mail.com'

SELECT @v1 = stuff(b, len(b),1,''), 
       @v2 = stuff(@s, 1, len(b),'') 
FROM (SELECT left(@s, charindex(':', @s)) b) a

SELECT @v1 v1,@v2 v2
```

Result:

```
v1  v2
--- ------------
XYZ xyz@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100)
SET @var='XYZ:xyz@mail.com'

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@var, 1, CHARINDEX(':',@var)-1) as var1 -- get part till :
,SUBSTRING(@var, CHARINDEX(':',@var)+1, LEN(@var)) AS var2 -- get part after :
```

Explained:

substring get's a part of a string from start_position to end_position

SUBSTRING( string, start_position, end_position)

charindex get's the position of a character inside a string

CHARINDEX( character_to_search, string_to_search_in)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx