# How to split a string into variables in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string which looks like `BAT | CAT | RAT | MAT` I want to split this string into 4 parts and then store them into 4 different variables say .. @a,@b,@c,@d respectively.

How can it be done in sql?

Comment: Use CHARINDEX, look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: is this helpful ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Comment: As the problem you face
this thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953115/dividing-a-string-into-two-parts-and-selecting-into-two-variables

Answer (score 14):

for splitting around a char :

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR (100)= 'cat | bat | sat'

SELECT items
INTO #STRINGS 
FROM dbo.split(@A,'|')
```

also see this link

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max);
set @test = 'Peter/Parker/Spiderman/Marvel';
set @test = Replace(@test, '/', '.');

SELECT ParseName(@test, 4) --returns Peter
SELECT ParseName(@test, 3) --returns Parker
SELECT ParseName(@test, 2) --returns Spiderman
SELECT ParseName(@test, 1) --returns Marvel
```

[SQL Server 2005 : split string into array and get array(x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645354/sql-server-2005-split-string-into-array-and-get-arrayx)

workarounds for splitting strings:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: ParseName is the standard clever answer, but it is actually not really a very good answer, because it is expecting the `sysname` data type. Just do normal string shredding.

Comment: @ErikE can you please elaborate on why one should avoid `ParseName` because this seems to be very alluring piece of code to me.

Comment: Ok I just realized that one can split only 4 parameters, if there is a 5th one it would simply return null. Am I wrong?

Comment: actually, you are right, please visit the links for more info.

Comment: What if you want to use periods? What if you want strings longer than 255 characters? Have you looked at the code for ParseName--it's very ugly if I recall correctly. Abusing system functions gives me the willies. It just seems a bad idea. What if you only have 3 tokens instead of 4 and ask for #4?

Answer (score 9):

Nice and simple.
(Using PATINDEX in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.)

```
DECLARE @string varchar(25) = 'BAT | CAT | RAT | MAT'
DECLARE @one varchar(5) = null
DECLARE @two varchar(5) = null
DECLARE @three varchar(5) = null
DECLARE @four varchar(5) = null

BEGIN

      SET @one = SUBSTRING(@string, 0, PATINDEX('%|%', @string)) 
      SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, LEN(@one + '|') + 1, LEN(@string))

      SET @two = SUBSTRING(@string, 0, PATINDEX('%|%', @string))
      SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, LEN(@two + '|') + 1, LEN(@string))

      SET @three = SUBSTRING(@string, 0, PATINDEX('%|%', @string))
      SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, LEN(@three + '|') + 1, LEN(@string))

      SET @four = @string

      SELECT @one AS Part_One, @two AS Part_Two, @three AS Part_Three, @four AS Part_Four
END
```

Answer (score 7):

You can split the values and insert them in a table variable, then assign them to your  variables like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Value] NVARCHAR(128)
)   

DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'BAT | CAT | RAT | MAT'

DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@Value, '|', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Value])
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')))
FROM @xml.nodes('//r') T(c)

SELECT [ID] 
      ,[Value]
FROM @DataSource
```

The result if this query is:

[image]

Note, this technique is dynamic - it will split any count of strings split with `|` and store them in table variable table.

Comment: Is there any simpler way? I have a function which takes care of splitting a long string of arguments but I was looking for some simple way to split a string when number of arguments are known. \

Comment: This a well known technique for splitting strings and it is simple. If you have a function that is implementing this method you can use it anywhere you need.