# Display transform horizontal to Vertical of the strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Declare @String Varchar(80)
Set @string ='chennai,mumbai,Bangalore,Hyderabad,pune'

I want to output like this

```
chennai
mumbai 
Bangalore
Hyderabad
Pune
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698318/how-to-split-a-string-into-variables-in-sql

Comment: This may help you

Comment: SQL Server has no data type called "array", so your question is unclear.